# how to load large datasets of numpy arrays in order to train a CNN model in tensorflow2.1.0

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm training a convolutional neural network (CNN) model for a binary classification task in tensorflow2.1.0.
The feature of each instance is a 4-dimensional numpy array with shape of (50, 50, 50, 2), in which the type of each element is float32.
The label of each instance is 1 or 0
My largest training dataset can contain up to ~100 millions of instances.

To efficiently train the model, is it best to serialize my training data and store it in a set of files with TFrecord format, and then load them with tf.data.TFRecordDataset() and parse them with tf.data.map()?
If so, could you show me an example of how to serialize the pairs of feature-label and store them into TFrecord files, then how to load and parse them?
I did not find appropriate example in the website of Tensorflow.

Or is there any better way to store and load the huge datasets? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to efficiently build data pipeline without TFRecord click this[link it was very useful](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-efficient-data-pipelines-using-tensorflow-8f647f03b4ce)

To extract images from **directory** efficiently then click this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images?authuser=1).

Hope this helped you.